# Articles before common nouns when they are used with proper nouns (names)

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article, proper-nouns

> I read an article about (a/the/-) Winterlude festival (festival here
> is not part of the event's name).
>
> In 2015, she published (a/the/-)
> book Innocent thoughts of the Innocent mind.

Should I use articles in these sentences or not? Please do not offer to rephrase, I want to know more about these particular grammar structures.

Comment: Is the title of the book "Innocent Thoughts of the Innocent Mind"? If so, it should be capitalized as I have done here. Otherwise, it looks like the title is "Innocent", then your sentence continues with "thoughts..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, usually you would use *the* here - you are thinking of a specific one, and you either expect the reader to know which one you mean, or intend by using *the* to convey to them that there is a specific one.

It is possible to use *a*, but it is unusual, and suggests something like "I didn't know this thing existed until that moment", with perhaps a bit of surprise that such a thing should exist at all.

For the book, both are possible. Using *the* suggests that you have some familiarity with it, whether or not your readers do; *a* suggests that you don't know it, or that you expect your readers not to have heard of it. There is not a clear separation between the two cases, though.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation is of great help!